# Argue whether or not it is possible that, in a group of 1009 people, each person is friends with exactly 3 people?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For this question. Is that ok I just simply use 1009/3 to show it can't be or I have to show something else? I am totally confusing.

Comment: Dividing by 3 isn't correct. Imagine the smaller case of Adam, Betty, Chris and Dave whom are friends. Each has 3 friends.

Comment: ... assuming friendship is symmetric ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with $1009$ vertices, one vertex representing each person in the group. Join two vertices $u$ and $v$ by an edge if and only if $u$ and $v$ are friends. Then the degree of each vertex equals the number of friends that the corresponding person has. If each person has exactly $3$ friends, then each vertex has degree $3$. Therefore, the total degree would be $3\times 1009 = 3027$. This is an odd number, contradicting the fact that the total degree must be an even number. Thus not everyone can have exactly three friends.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) tells us that for any graph $G=(V,E)$ we have:

$$\sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v)=2|E|$$